# Plotting the decay envelope for dampening function without the usual "fit with a decaying sinusoidal first" method?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

To be more clear, by the decay rate of a dampening function I mean fitting the exponential curve to the amplitude of the damped oscillations and see how it decays.

Something like the following :

*Damped Sine wave*
[image: Damped Sine wave]

but for my graph which is certainly not smooth like the above and whose picture I still cannot upload due to my low reputation ):

Now I can think of two ways to do it to:

1. First fit a damped sinusoidal to my data points and then find the decay rate using this damped sinusoidal function.
2. Break the function into a finite number of intervals and find the maximum value of the function in that interval. Then, treat it as the amplitude and fit these with an exponential.

I though think both the above implementations will be very imprecise.
The damped sinusoidal won't be a good fit for my function as even though ti would probably capture the decay in my function it cannot keep up with it's non-uniform oscillations.
For the second case I am guessing the accuracy depends on the length I choose to discretize the function with and so it's not clear what should be the appropriate length to choose.

Is there a method to do this that is better than the above two or maybe that uses the in-built Python functions?

**Edit:**

Here is my plot:

Note: The erratic fast local oscillations are what made me think why the damped sine method might be less accurate for this (even though it seems that it might actually be more accurate as shown in K.CI's answer)

[image]

Comment: You could loop through your sinal and detect if the previous and next points are lower than the current. This should characterize a peak. Collect these then fit your exponential decay only on the peaks. Would this satisfy your needs?

Comment: @K.Cl Isn't this just like the 2nd method mentioned above with a lot larger iterations?

Comment: Essentially yes, but it's easy to compute. It depends only on the length of your array, so it's quite efficient. The fitting algorithm will consume much more processing power. In the figure you provided, isn't it doing basically what is mentioned in 2? I mean, you could try to simultaneously fit a sine and exponential decay, but I don't think it'll give you much more info.

Comment: Also, I must mention that the method 2 is used some stuff I work on, specifically to obtain the T2 decay curves in NMR CPMG experiments. These curves are composed of the peaks of the oscillations and are later on fitted with multiexponentials in a roundabout way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some toy functions that could help you decide on your method. I've found the exponential factors using the method I described (only peaks, found naively) and also by fitting the whole curve. If you could provide an example data then we might approach a problem directly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def exp(t, A, lbda):
    r"""y(t) = A \cdot \exp(-\lambda t)"""
    return A * np.exp(-lbda * t)

def sine(t, omega, phi):
    r"""y(t) = \sin(\omega \cdot t + phi)"""
    return np.sin(omega * t + phi)

def damped_sine(t, A, lbda, omega, phi):
    r"""y(t) = A \cdot \exp(-\lambda t) \cdot \left( \sin \left( \omega t + \phi ) \right)"""
    return exp(t, A, lbda) * sine(t, omega, phi)

def add_noise(y, loc=0, scale=0.01):
    noise = np.random.normal(loc=loc, scale=scale, size=y.shape)
    return y + noise
```

You can increase the noise with the `scale` value in `add_noise`. Let's get some data:

```py
# Real vals
t = np.linspace(0, 5, num=300)
A = 1
lbda = 1
omega = 8 * np.pi
phi = 0

real_y = damped_sine(t, A, lbda, omega, phi)
np.random.seed(42)
noisy_y = add_noise(real_y, scale=0.05)
```

The plot: [image: First]

Naive method to find peaks:

```py
def find_peaks(x, y):
    peak_x = []
    peak_vals = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if i == len(y) - 1:
            continue
        if (y[i-1] < y[i]) and (y[i+1] < y[i]):
            peak_x.append(x[i])
            peak_vals.append(y[i])
    return np.array(peak_x), np.array(peak_vals)
```

Yields this: [image: Second]

Fitting only the peaks with the exponential:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp, noisy_peak_x, noisy_peak_y)
print(*[f"{val:.2f}+/-{err:.2f}" for val, err in zip(popt, np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))])
print(A, lbda)
```

Yields: `1.06+/-0.09; 1.39+/-0.13`. Pretty bad, but the noise is quite big *and* the peaks are badly found. Here's the plot: [image: Fit]

If you fit the entire sinusoidal curve, the result is better:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(damped_sine, t, noisy_y)
print(*[f"{val:.2f}+/-{err:.2f}" for val, err in zip(popt, np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))])
print(A, lbda, omega, phi)
```

Yields this `1.02+/-0.02 1.03+/-0.03 25.16+/-0.03 -0.02+/-0.02` compared to `1 1 25.13 0`, which is quite better, after all, there's many more points. Here's the graph: [image: Fourth]

If you expand the peak finding method to consider a window:

```py
def find_peaks_window(x, y, window=1):
    peak_x = []
    peak_vals = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if i < window:
            continue
        if i > len(y) - window:
            continue
        left_side = y[i-window:i]
        right_side = y[i+1:i+1+window]
        if all(left_side < y[i]) and all(right_side < y[i]):
            peak_x.append(x[i])
            peak_vals.append(y[i])
    return np.array(peak_x), np.array(peak_vals)
```

You get this `0.93+/-0.04 0.78+/-0.05` compared to `1 1`: [image]

Comment: Thank you. As for "If you could provide an example data then we might approach a problem directly" My data is basically a damped curve that I am outputing from a simulation . I want to calculate the damping rate of this curve but I am not allowed to post pictures yet because of my reputation. I will try to see if I can somehow put a link to it.

Comment: Sure. You can try to add the data to a pastebin and put the link in your post.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: Also, can you explicitly show how you go from finding popt (the optimal parameters) to plotting the graphs? I tried to reproduce your toy-plots with `plt.plot(noisy_x,damped_sine(noisy_x,*popt),'-r')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Oof, that is very noisy. But the exponential part appears to reach 0 close to t=100, so you could try to fit an exponential just to the beginning of the curve. I think it'll be a very iterative process. Try various methods. I've also heard about people applying Fourier transforms to separate noise from signal, although I've never successfully done that in Python. For your question, what's your error specifically? Sorry, I didn't put the plot commands for brevity but I'll add them later when I get back home.

Comment: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'` This is the error I get. Also, from your comment it seems you do agree that my plot would be better suited for an exponential fitting rather than the damped sinusoidal. I just want to confirm if I understood you correctly. Also, deploying fourier transform for this seems like an overkill (??) given that I just require the the decay which seems apparent for range t=0 - 100 and that I am not at all adept at doing it in Python. (:

Comment: Somewhere, you're multiplying a list by a numpy float. Maybe it's your `noisy_x`? Also, note that the exponential fit is obtained with what I called `noisy_peak_x`, and should be plotted as `plt.plot(noisy_peak_x, exp(noisy_peak_x, *popt))`. Note `exp` instead of `damped_sine`. If you're plotting the full signal, then you don't use `noisy_peak_x`, but `t`, since your abscissa values aren't subdivided, like `plt.plot(t, damped_sine(t, *popt))`.

Comment: Regarding: `Also, from your comment it seems you do agree that my plot would be better suited for an exponential fitting rather than the damped sinusoidal. I just want to confirm if I understood you correctly.` Yes, that appears to be more appropriate for your curve in my opinion. I agree, Fourier is overkill.

Comment: You may find my other question relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798695/why-does-the-peak-finding-algorithm-i-use-not-work-for-properly-for-some-cases