# Why does the peak finding algorithm I use not work for properly for some cases?

Tags: python, plot, scipy

I am trying to find the damping rate of some oscillations that I output from a simulation.

For that, I first find the peaks of these oscillations and fit them with an exponential fit.

The method works fine for most cases but for a case I encountered yesterday I found that the method does not work properly and there was no visible reason I could find for it to not work. There seems to be some issue with the peak finding I used that somehow misses the peaks for some cases.

Here is the program for finding the peaks:
(Note: Variables in the list Tarr, Zarr, Alpharr are taken from a cell run previously)

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def exp(t, A, lbda):
  return A * np.exp(-lbda * t)

def find_peaks(x, y):
    peak_x = []
    peak_vals = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if i == 0:
          if y[i+1]<y[i]:
            peak_x.append(x[i])
            peak_vals.append(y[i])
          else:
            continue
        if i == len(y) - 1:
            continue
        if (y[i-1] < y[i]) and (y[i+1] < y[i]):
            peak_x.append(x[i])
            peak_vals.append(y[i])
    return np.array(peak_x), np.array(peak_vals)

Tarr=[Tplot0,Tplot1,Tplot2,Tplot3,Tplot4]
Zarr=[Zrel0,Zrel1,Zrel2,Zrel3,Zrel4]
Alpharr=[alpha0,alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4]

for x0,y0,alf in zip(Tarr,Zarr,Alpharr):
  
  peak_x0,peak_y0=find_peaks(x0,y0)
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp, peak_x0, peak_y0)
  print(*[f"{val:.2f} +/- {err:.2f} __ " for val, err in zip(popt, np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))])
  print("decay rate = ",popt[1])
  plt.plot(x0,y0)
  plt.plot(peak_x0,exp(peak_x0,*popt),'-r', label=str((popt[0]))+"*exp(-"+str((popt[1]))+")")
  plt.xlabel("time")
  plt.ylabel("Zrel ")
  plt.title("n = "+str(n)+" ; alpha = "+str(alf))
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

Contrast these two cases:

**1)**

[image]

**2)**

[image]

In the second case, the oscillations are increased before it damps to zero while in the first case these oscillations are very less (just around 2). I would have expected my algorithm to almost connect the peaks in the second figure (to give the best fit) .But it seems it misses the first two peaks  for some reason.

Comment: `y[i-1] < y[i] and y[i+1] < y[i]` will mis a peak that has repeated values.

Comment: Do you mean when `y[i-1]=y[i]`?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don' think that is the case. Also, the plot does not have repeated peaks.

Comment: Anyway, I guarantee that `y[i-1] < y[i] and y[i+1] < y[i]` will mis a peak that has repeated values, believe it or not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I replaced the above command with `y[i-1]<=y[i] and y[i+1]<=y[i]` and the results don't change. The replaced should have accounted for missed peaks ryt or do you have something better in mind to account for the peaks I miss?

Comment: While I agree the simple peak finding algorithm will miss if two peaks have exactly the same value, seeing as this are results from a simulation, I find it extremely difficult to believe two neighboring values will have exactly the same value. Anyway, I recommend you plot the peak x and y values together with the damped sine (as markers only, not lines) to see if/which peaks are being missed. Also, if you could provide the data for a good and a bad case in a pastebin, it would help us pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @K.Cl Indeed if you look at the "bad" case, it does not look like any two peaks have same value.  I am trying to see a way on how to paste my data in a pastebin, I have never done that before,

Comment: See: https://pastebin.com/. It's very easy, just paste your x and y arrays in and create: Test: https://pastebin.com/vUf5RaVz

Comment: @K.Cl Will I have to copy the list from the output or just the variables will work? Because my lists are too long (3958930 elements) to be outputted If I output them then I get `IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.`

Comment: Typically my arrays aren't that large. In your case, try this: `x_array.tofile('x_array.txt', sep=',')`. Then copy-paste the text file to pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you probably can look at scipy for [peak finding algorithms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html),`scipy.signal.find_peaks`. Probably you need to specify the *prominence* value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).